# Rank the closest date, but not if date has already been used in previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Complicated to summarize the issue in the title, and in text so check the IMG for visual explanation.

I've got an issue joining two tables. The date from the first table (`startdatetable`) should get the next/closest date in the other table (`enddatetable`). This is to 99% easy done with rank, because most rows have a `startdate` that can find the next `enddate`, and before another `enddate` is available there is a new `startdate`.

However, if there are two `startdate`s and only one `enddate` available the `startdate`s will join the same `enddate`.

What I'm trying to do is, that if a date has been used in the row before, it should not be used in the next row.

The rows I want are highlighted.

[image: IMG]

The SQL I started out with looked like

```
select *
from (
    select rank() over (partition by tid order by enddate asc) as rnk
        , id, startdate, enddate
    from startdateTable
    inner join enddateTable on startdateTable.ID = enddateTable.id
        and enddateTable.enddate > startdateTable.startdate
) q
where q.rnk = 1
```

This gets me the following result. The last row should instead get the 2100 date, since the 2020-06 date has been used in the previous row.

[image: Result]

Comment: Added to the main description.

Comment: . . You need to show what the two tables look like.  Without that information, it is not clear what you are asking.  You could also set up a db/sql fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two tables and you want to align them, then you can use `row_number()`:

```
select s.id, s.startdate, e.enddate
from (select s.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by startdate) as seqnum
      from startdateTable
     ) s join
     (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by enddate) as seqnum
      from enddateTable
     ) e
     on e.id = s.id and e.seqnum = s.seqnum
```

Comment: This looks very promising.  Will give it a few testruns.

Comment: this solved my initial problem,  no ran into some new once..
THANKS!